# No Plus Sign Button or Edit Button in IOS Contacts App

Tags: iphone, applications, contacts

The Contacts App on my iPhone 4 (with IOS 5.1) has no '+' in the top right corner to add a contact and no "edit" in the top right corner to edit a contact. My friends do have this. How to it get these buttons to show up?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking at a subscribed contacts list, rather than one of your own that you have read/write access to.  Go 'back' all the way to list you contacts accounts, and ensure you are actually looking at your own contacts.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to a friend's new iPhone. It appears to be a bug in iOS 5. The solution is to enable iCloud synching for your contacts. Then the '+' button should appear. The edit button should be there also. You can then turn off iCloud synching if you'd like. But it looks like to have to do iCloud synching at least once.